# Replace looping-over-axes with broadcasting

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

Say I have:

```
a = np.array([[2, 4],
              [6, 8]])    
b = np.array([[1, 3],
              [1, 5]])
```

I want to get to:

```
c = np.array([[20,32],
              [28, 44]])
```

where `c` is the result of multiplying each column of `a` by `b`, then summing that result along the first axis.

I.e.:

```
print(np.sum(a[:, 0] * b, axis=1))
[20 32]

print(np.sum(a[:, 1] * b, axis=1))
[28 44]
```

Can I do through broadcasting rather than:

- using `np.apply_along_axis` or
- looping through each column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

```
b.dot(a).T
```

Alternatively, using [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) (for the kicks maybe) -

```
np.einsum('ij,ki->jk',a,b)
```

Comment: 1+ for the kick.

Comment: And `einsum` will be slower for smaller arrays and faster for larger ones?

Comment: @BradSolomon With no axis aligning requirement, I would think that as you increase the number of sum-reductions, i.e. work with large arrays, `np.dot` would fair better.