# Replace looping-over-axes with broadcasting, pt 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

Earlier I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200611/replace-looping-over-axes-with-broadcasting) where the answer used `np.dot`, taking advantage of the fact that a dot product involves a sum of products.  (To my understanding.)

Now I have a similar issue where I don't think `dot` will apply, because in place of a sum I want to take an element-wise diagonal.  If it does, I haven't been able to apply it correctly.

Given a matrix `x` and array `err`:

```
x = np.matrix([[ 0.02984406, -0.00257266],
               [-0.00257266,  0.00320312]])

err = np.array([  7.6363226 ,  13.16548267])
```

My current implementation with loop is:

```
res = np.array([np.sqrt(np.diagonal(x * err[i])) for i in range(err.shape[0])])

print(res)
[[ 0.47738755  0.15639712]
 [ 0.62682649  0.20535487]]
```

which takes the diagonal of `x.dot(i)` for each `i` in `err`.  Could this be vectorized?  In other words, can the output of `x * err` be 3-dimensional, with `np.diagonal` then yielding a 2d array, with one element for each diagonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Program:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.matrix([[ 0.02984406, -0.00257266],
               [-0.00257266,  0.00320312]])

err = np.array([  7.6363226 ,  13.16548267])
diag = np.diagonal(x)
ans = np.sqrt(diag*err[:,np.newaxis])  # sqrt of outer product
print(ans)

# use out keyword to avoid making new numpy array for many times.
ans = np.empty(x.shape, dtype=x.dtype)
for i in range(100):
    ans = np.multiply(diag, err, out=ans)
    ans = np.sqrt(ans, out=ans)
```

Result:

```
[[ 0.47738755  0.15639712]
 [ 0.62682649  0.20535487]]
```

Comment: could use out keyword to avoid allocating new numpy array, which is slow.

Comment: sqrt faster than **0.5 in old version of python. not sure about new. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327002/which-is-faster-in-python-x-5-or-math-sqrtx I am usually too lazy to type sqrt

Comment: don't worry about allocating new array if you only do this for once, instead of many times.

Comment: are you writing some kind of least square fitting?

Comment: Yes, with the intention of generalizing to cases with more than one `y` vector.  This finds the standard errors of the coefficients.  Why do you ask?

Comment: Have you searched if anyone has written code/library for that? writing new code is the last resort.

Comment: Yes, there are `statsmodels` and `sklearn` but I'm unsatisfied with both and in the process of tweaking them

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach making use of `diagonal-view` with [`ndarray.flat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html) into `x` and then use `broadcasting` for element-wise multiplication, like so -

```
np.sqrt(x.flat[::x.shape[1]+1].A1 * err[:,None])
```

Sample run -

```
In [108]: x = np.matrix([[ 0.02984406, -0.00257266],
     ...:                [-0.00257266,  0.00320312]])
     ...: 
     ...: err = np.array([  7.6363226 ,  13.16548267])
     ...: 

In [109]: np.sqrt(x.flat[::x.shape[1]+1].A1 * err[:,None])
Out[109]: 
array([[ 0.47738755,  0.15639712],
       [ 0.62682649,  0.20535487]])
```

Runtime test to see how a `view` helps over `np.diagonal` that creates a copy -

```
In [104]: x = np.matrix(np.random.rand(5000,5000))

In [105]: err = np.random.rand(5000)

In [106]: %timeit np.diagonal(x)*err[:,np.newaxis]
10 loops, best of 3: 66.8 ms per loop

In [107]: %timeit x.flat[::x.shape[1]+1].A1 * err[:,None]
10 loops, best of 3: 37.7 ms per loop
```